# EC2 Instance cannot connect to other Amazon Web Service

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

I was browsing the web using Firefox with my EC2 instance located in Ashburn, Virginia (IP Addr: 54.159.107.46) I visited `www.supremenewyork.com` and it did not load (other websites like Google did load.) I did some research and found the IP of Supreme's site: 52.6.25.180 . I found out that the location of that IP is ALSO IN ASHBURN, Virginia, which could only mean that supreme is using AWS to host their site. This is an issue for my instance because I want to connect to supreme using it, but because the IPs are in the same Server Building or in Amazon's IP range I can't. Is there a workaround to this issue? Please help.

By the way: I tried pinging Supreme's IP from my EC2 instance – 100% packet loss.

NOTE THAT I CAN ACCESS SUPREME FROM MY HOME COMPUTER: IT IS NOT DOWN

Is there a security problem because I am trying to connect to their site?

Comment: can you ping the security groups detail of your ec2 instance ? is outbound traffic on all port is open ?

Comment: @AmitK Yeah Outbound connection are 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Pings can be disabled if you are not having ICMP protocol enabled in your aws security groups. also could you paste the image of your ec2 machine's inbound and outbound security rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran some tests locally and on AWS machines. My conclusion: `www.supremenewyork.com` blocks traffic that originates from AWS. It is easy to block traffic from AWS using IP tables. AWS publishes [IP Address Ranges](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) and it is easy to write a simple script like [AWS Blocker](https://github.com/corbanworks/aws-blocker) to block all traffic from AWS IPs.

Why do some vendors block traffic from AWS? Increasing DDoS traffic and bot attacks from AWS hosted machines. Many attackers exploit compromised machines running in AWS to launch their attack. I have seen too many such incidents. AWS does its best to thwart such attempts. But if you see most of the attacks from a set of IP ranges, naturally you will try to block traffic from those IPs. I suspect the same in this case.

The website is not pingable because ICMP traffic is blocked from all IPs. There is nothing you can do (unless you go through a VPN) to access the vendor website from your EC2 machine.

Comment: Thank you! If www.supremenewyork.com allowed traffic from any and all IPs, would the HTTP request take a lot shorter to perform than if I did it in say Los Angeles?